# Gravity Forms API exits the page when fetching more than 2000 entries

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have this weird behaviour when trying to fetch more than 2000 records via the Gravity Forms api, the methods used for fetching the records is as follows:

```
$search_criteria["field_filters"]["mode"] = "all";

$all_entries_submitted = GFAPI::get_entries(2,$search_criteria,null,array('offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 3000 ));
```

Any ideas why could this be?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a possible network timeout. What do you mean exits the page?

Comment: You might try fetching in batches of smaller number until you have the whole thing.

Comment: By "exists the page" I mean that anything below that line of code is never reached, like an exception is thrown but no error appears..  I also noticed that other forms that I have actually do retrieve all existing records (9000+) just the 2 forms do not. Could it be that these two forms need more memory allowed in php?

Comment: That also sound plausible.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem:

When I increased the allowed memory size in php to a huge number (1gb) the script eventually returned the records (after a few minutes)

```
ini_set('memory_limit','1000M');
$search_criteria["field_filters"]["mode"] = "all";

$all_entries_submitted = GFAPI::get_entries(2,$search_criteria,null,array('offset' => 0, 'page_size' => 3000 ));
```